# Kotlin Enforce Generic Override Type

Tags: android, kotlin

I am extending from `ViewModelProvider.Factory` and therefore I need to override `fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T`. I want to enforce this T type from outside the class, passing it to the class when initialising the factory. My idea was to have something like this:

```
class BaseViewModelFactory<T>(val creator: () -> T) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val gearSearchViewModel: T = creator() as T
        return gearSearchViewModel
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the `T` type defined in the `BaseViewModelFactory` is being treated as a different type than the one defined in the `create` function, therefore needing that `as T` cast in the end. Is there a way to avoid this, and enforce the outer `T` type into the inner `T` function type?

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally redeclared the type parameter `T` in the declaration of the `create` function. Remove `<T : ViewModel?>` so that `T` in the function refers to the `T` declared in the class definition.

Comment: This is the thing, this is a framework class. Perhaps I cannot do anything about it. The type T is actually defined in a `get` function, that then calls the `create` function.

Comment: this is what I am trying to avoid: `private val searchViewModel: GearSearchViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, BaseViewModelFactory { GearSearchViewModel(SearchRepository(SearchRemoteDataSource())) }).get(GearSearchViewModel::class.java) }` You see that I explicitly need to define the type in the `get` function. I would like for it to be the type returned by the lambda function, but I think the way this was designed does not allow that. Unless I extend all those classes, which I do not really want to do.